# Old Site from 2005 appearing on certain computers

Tags: wordpress, web, hosting

One of my clients a well repested local bar and brewerly has been complaining that them, and several costumers are getting the website from 2005, and when they try to get to the wordpress they get a ulgy error page. On my computer, and several of my friends get the current site with no problems what so ever. I have never heard or encounter something like this, really need help.

The website is atwaterbeer.com

here are some images of the issues

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzh_65L4dosxeWRuU3g4S1hGTXB3WXk0enFkQWI5ZXl6OWlV/view?usp=sharing

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&ik=75ba71b2c7&view=fimg&th=15ab62eb92aa0ee3&attid=0.1&disp=inline&safe=1&attbid=ANGjdJ8O8HaS9XeGMSXlhfzjUy5uSZv54tEtcWquVvt4wG20yBKT1MwGh4-VEkSfayTBtulyF3GWlVRLPY2HPsO0Nt2ZcbXGWNQWakrdBoSKgPmMxvhgmJX15akiudg&ats=1489255350834&rm=15ab62eb92aa0ee3&zw&sz=w1424-h637

Comment: Second link doesn't work, it looks like a link to a resource in your gmail account, only you can access it.

Answer (score 0):

You have DNS entries with A (IPv4) and AAAA (IPv6) records, but they point to different servers. IPv4 points to Apache, IPv6 points to IIS.

IPv6 record is wrong because it points to your old server, you can confirm this by using an [IPv6 proxy website](http://www.ipv6proxy.net).

You need to change AAAA record so it points to your current server. If you cannot find your current server's IPv6 address or if your hosting company does not provide one, **your priority is to remove the bad AAAA record from DNS, this should fix the issue for most of your users** (after an hour or so due to TTL time).

Comment: How do I fix that

Comment: You need to find out what is the IPv6 address of the correct server and change it in DNS settings of the website's domain registar. Your hosting company should be able to provide that IP address or if they don't have IPv6 then just remove AAAA record.

Comment: It's hard to tell why it started just now because I don't know the DNS history of that domain. You can check for yourself how it looks when accessing the website via IPv6 by using this IPv6 proxy [http://www.ipv6proxy.net](http://www.ipv6proxy.net).